# Отклоненные групповые политики

Tags: windows, active-directory

Есть 4 групповых политики. Все 4 прилинкованы к одному подразделению. Каждая из 4 применяется только к одной группе пользователей. Из каждой удалена группа "Прошедшие проверку"

Пользователь входит в каждую из 4 групп.

gpresult показывает, что одна групповая политика применилась, а остальные три были отклонены

```
Настроенные расширения Реестр 
Принудительный Нет 
Отключено Нет 
Редакция AD (1), SYSVOL (65535) 
Причина отказа Отказано в доступе (фильтрация ограничений безопасности)
```

Если в отклоненную групповую политику добавить группу "Прошедшие проверку" то она тоже начинает применяться.

На контроллере домена gpresult для этого пользователя показывает, что применяются две политики и две отклоняются по причине безопасности

```
Фильтрация:  Отказано (безопасность)
```

В чем моя ошибка? Почему применяется только одна политика?

**Update**

Почему-то игнорировался вызов

```
gpupdate /target:user /force
```

после перелогина ситуация немного поменялась

- На контроллере (Win2003) применились все 4 политики
- На клиенте (Win8) применились три политики. Не применилась та политика, в группу которой входит не непосредственно, а через другую группу. Т.е.

  ```
  GPO -> Group1 -> Group2 -> User
  ```

  Если пользователя добавить в `Group1` то и эта политика применяется

Т.е. на данный момент вопросы звучат так:

1. Почему не отрабатывался `gpupdate`?
2. Почему не применяется политика через делегирование?